# How to call a JavaScript function, declared in <head>, in the body when I want to call it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working JavaScript function declared in the head of an HTML page. I know how to create a button and call the function when the user clicks the button. I want to call it myself some where on the page:

```
myfunction();
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 30):

You can call it like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var person = { name: 'Joe Blow' };
            function myfunction() {
               document.write(person.name);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            myfunction();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result should be page with the only content: `Joe Blow`

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/HWreP/

Best regards!

Comment: Ok, yes that works, thanks. I now see that my problem is that in my real script, I create and initialize an object and my function is suppose to display the object's values when I call it - when I try that in the script tags, nothing happens. Is there a way to do this? as in: <script > person = new Object(); person.name="Joe Blow"; function display()  { document.write(person.name); } </script> then in body <script> display(); </script>

Comment: I edited my answer to fit to your first and second question. You can also see how it's working in the fiddle I've applied to the answer (http://jsfiddle.net/HWreP/).

Comment: Thanks again. I swear I tried what you demo here and it didn't work but now it does!? :( :) (I must have made some small mistake somewhere or else the gremlins decided to stop bothering me.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "myself".

Any JavaScript function can be called by an event, but you must have some sort of event to trigger it.

e.g. On page load:

```
<body onload="myfunction();">
```

Or on mouseover:

```
<table onmouseover="myfunction();">
```

As a result the first question is, "What do you want to do to cause the function to execute?"

After you determine that it will be much easier to give you a direct answer.

Comment: `myfunction;` doesn't do anything. You probably mean `myfunction();`.

Answer (score 3):

Just drop

```
<script>
myfunction();
</script>
```

in the body where you want it to be called, understanding that when the page loads and the browser reaches that point, that's when the call will occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the JavaScript code in script tags, rather than a separate function. `<script>//JS Code</script>` This way the code will get executes on Page Load.